# Which Protoc Does "Make" Command Use?

Tags: makefile, caffe, protoc

I am trying to build [LAB](https://github.com/wywu/LAB) which generate robust facial landmark.

In installation guide it says one needs to install Caffe prerequisites which I'd checked CUDA and BLAS well installed on my AWS EC2 instance.

Then I git cloned and typed `make` under the cloned git folder named in LAB

But it returns following error

```
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
In file included from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:4:0:
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^
In file included from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:4:0:
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:23:35: fatal error: google/protobuf/arena.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:588: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o] Error 1
```

The error above looks like I am using old version of `libprotoc` so if I type in `which protoc` it returns

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin//protoc
```

and for `protoc --version` it returns `libprotoc 3.5.1`

and for `whereis protoc` it returns

```
protoc: /usr/local/bin/protoc /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/protoc /usr/share/man/man1/protoc.1.gz
```

Thus since it looks like I have another protoc in `/usr/local/bin` I had checked its version via `/usr/local/bin/protoc --version` which returns

```
libprotoc 3.3.0
```

Hereby I have two problems:

1) I don't know if I use `make` cmd, which protoc being referred.
2) I don't know the error requires which version of protoc.

How can I check and get the proper information regarding above two problems?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try something like `PROTOC=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/protoc make`
2. Make sure compiler got correct path to protobuf headers with appropriate `-I` option.